# Typescript undefined is not an object when pushing to array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to push to an array but it keeps giving me this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

here is the source where I am simply adding to an array. I take the obsevable from the firestore collection and loop through it. Why is it giving me this error when the array of category objects is right there. `categories: Category[];`

```
transactions: Observable<Transaction[]>;
categories: Category[];

private organizeData() {
    let category: Category;

    this.transactions.forEach(v => {
      for (let i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
        category = {name: v[i].category, totalSpent: v[i].amount};
        this.categories.push(category);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`categories: Category[]` is just the declaration of an array, you need to actually create a new array and assign it to the field:

```
categories: Category[] = []
```

Answer (score 4):

You are not initiating your array `categories` so it will return undefined. Try:

`categories: Category[] = [];`